# Oracle delete from tableA where a duplicate row is in tableB

Tags: oracle

As the title says, I am looking for a way to remove all rows from TableA where there is a matching row in TableB.
the Tables A & B have about 30 columns in them so a WHERE A.col1 = B.col1 etc would be a little problematical. Ideally I was hoping for something like

```
DELETE FROM tableA WHERE IN TableB
```

*(overly simplified by this type of thing)*

Comment: You have two answers below which should work for you, but I feel like asking if you will have a long term for doing this?  I can't think of a way to easily maintain this constraint on a long term basis.

Comment: if the two tables have same type/name columns, I'd go with a natural join to find dupes/generate statements for deletion.  https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefsqljnaturaljoin.html

Answer (score 1):

`IN` clause can compare all columns returned from select

```
DELETE FROM tableA WHERE ( col1,col2,col3,.. ) IN ( select col1,col2,col3... FROM TableB );
```

Answer (score 0):

The brute force way to establish if two records from each table are the same is to just compare every column:

```
DELETE
FROM tableA a
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tableB b WHERE a.col1 = b.col1 AND a.col2 = b.col2 AND ...
    a.col30 = b.col30);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create function which checks structures of tables and, if they are the same, creates string containing correct conditions to compare.

For example here are two tables:

```
create table t1 (id, name, age) as (
  select 1, 'Tom', 67 from dual union all
  select 2, 'Tia', 42 from dual union all
  select 3, 'Bob', 16 from dual );

create table t2 (id, name, age) as (
  select 1, 'Tom', 51 from dual union all
  select 3, 'Bob', 16 from dual );
```

Now use function:

```
select generate_condition('T1', 'T2') from dual;
```

result:

```
T1.ID = T2.ID and T1.NAME = T2.NAME and T1.AGE = T2.AGE
```

Copy this, paste and run `delete` query:

```
delete from t1 where exists (select 1 from t2 where <<PASTE_HERE>>)
```

Here is the function, adjust it if needed. I used `user_tab_columns` so if tables are on different schemas you need `all_tab_columns` and compare owners too. If you have Oracle 11g you can replace loop with `listagg()`. Second table has to contain all columns of first table and they have to be same type and length.

```
create or replace function generate_condition(i_t1 in varchar2, i_t2 in varchar2) 
    return varchar2 is
    v varchar2(1000) := '';
begin
    for rec in (select column_name, u2.column_id
                  from user_tab_cols u1 
                  left join (select * from user_tab_cols where table_name = i_t2) u2
                  using (column_name, data_type, data_length) 
                  where u1.table_name = i_t1 order by u1.column_id) 
    loop
        if rec.column_id is null then 
            v := 'ERR: incompatible structures';
            goto end_loop;
        end if;
        v := v||' and '||i_t1||'.'||rec.column_name
                ||' = '||i_t2||'.'||rec.column_name;
    end loop;
    << end_loop >>
    return(ltrim(v, ' and '));
end;
```

If you want to avoid running process manually you need dynamic PL/SQL.

Answer (score 0):

```
create table tableA (a NUMBER, b VARCHAR2(5), c INTEGER);
create table tableB (a NUMBER, b VARCHAR2(5), c INTEGER);
```

As you said

> WHERE A.col1 = B.col1 etc would be a little problematical

you could intersect the tables and mention all columns from tableA one time, like this:

```
delete tableA 
 where (a,b,c) in (select * from tableA
                   intersect
                   select * from tableB);
```